# Can Socket.AcceptAsync() function reuse its argument SocketAsyncEventArgs?

Tags: c#, sockets

I just began my new C# socket programming.

I pass SocketAsyncEventArgs for Socket.ReceiveAsync() and reuse it again and again. It works okay.

But, if I do that again for Socket.AcceptAsync(), InvalidOperationException is thrown.
If I create new instance of SocketAsyncEventArgs for that and it's well.

Should I create SocketAsyncEventArgs for every Socket.AcceptAsync() call?
(If so, what not for Socket.ReceiveAsync()?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The main point about SocketAsyncEventArgs is that it's reusable.
However, you need 1 SocketAsyncEventArgs for every type of *Async method.

I've seen pool-classes made for this like:

```
class AsyncEventArgsPool {
    SocketAsyncEventArgs GetEventArgs(string method);
}
```

and you call that method with "Send", "Receive", "Accept" etc.... Implementation should be simple.

Comment: I tried to reuse SocketAsyncEventArgs *OnCompleted* EventHandler called AFTER ACCEPTED. Why can't I reuse OnCompleted()'s parameter(SocketAsyncEventArgs) ?